# Can I execute JavaScript on a foreign webpage using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to write a PHP script which executes code on a foreign website just like using the JS-console on that webpage. I don't want the server to act like the client on that certain webpage.

To make it even more difficult, the JavaScript must be executed on a different frame (when executing the JavaScript manually I'd switch to the correct console by clicking on the specific Frame in the dropdown menu above the console (Chrome)).

If I try to do something nearly impossible here, please don't hesitate to tell me exactly that.

Comment: Javascript is executed by clients, not servers (I'm not counting node.js).

Comment: Use [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), not to be confused with the Dutch football team though.

Comment: its what you asking is how to get content from other website then set as iframe then use js-console? maybe trace about other website vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to describe what your end goal is. You are probably going down the wrong path here. There is no way to add javascript to a page that you don't serve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean (and more detail would really help here). You want to automate something that you can do manually on a browser yourself, by manually running javascript on a webpage (via the console). The only reason I can think you would want to do this is to trigger an Ajax request/API call or submit a form.

This is technically possible, but it would be better to look for an actual API that you can talk to directly; you could do this by inspecting the network tab of the developer tools, but if they don't have a public API you may have to do a fair amount to fake the request; and if anything changes on the server it could all stop working.

If they don't have an API that you can call, or if they have put measures in place. Then there is a good chance that you are trying to misuse a website; and they may well put further measures in place to stop you (this is why captchas exist).

If you can figure out the details of a request to send, then you could use CURL to make the request - this page may help: https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

If you really still find that you need/want to actually run javascript on a remote page, then this is "browser automation", and while technically could be triggered from PHP - requires much more to make it possible. Selenium is primarily used to automate tests, but would allow you to do this: http://www.seleniumhq.org/ via JavascriptExecutor but I would recommend you do some futher searches for tutorials, as it's too large/broad to really cover here:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html